# How to match with Non-Ascii character using Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

How to match 4 char then jump one char(which is unknown for me, so whatever may be such as some other chinese or special character occurance) after 4 char again jump one char(which is unknown for me, so whatever may be such as some other chinese or special character occurance) again 4 etc.,

**My check string** : 1234 4567 7891 0934
this is 16digit char, each 4char separated by space.

**Main string**:
"ACCOUNT NUMBER NAME STATEMENT DATE PAYMENT DUE DATE 1234 4567 7891 0934 Jane Doe 01/01/2009 02/26/09 CREDIT LIMIT CREDIT AVAILABLE NEW BALANCE MINIMUM PAYMENT DUE ."

above text(Main string) comes from PDF document. which was extracted by **OCR** Engine.
since Main string has my check string, but it's separated by some unknown char instead of space. I tried replace with # to space in Visual studio's immediate window. but that space of in-between Main string's check string was not replaced. thus, I could able to say It is Non-ascii character, but seems like a space.

I could be able get rid from this issue by below code:

```
 string asAscii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            Encoding.Convert(
                Encoding.UTF8,
                Encoding.GetEncoding(
                    Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName,
                    new EncoderReplacementFallback(string.Empty),
                    new DecoderExceptionFallback()
                    ),
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString)
            )
        );
```

but,I would like to know Regex solution.
Even though non-ascii char occured, should be match with regex to check whether exists or not.

Comment: The blank spaces may be the issue.  There is standard ascii character (0x20) and then unicode spaces.  I would convert string to bytes an verify the ascii characters and scpaces.  The solution may just be to use a string replace to remove/change some characters.  Regex shouldn't be used for simple replacements.  String methods are more efficient than Regex.

Comment: yep! which makes sense.but,My consideration is to know some Regex solution for learning purposes.

Comment: You can still replaced the bad characters with Regex.  But you have to have some idea of which characters.  You would need to know exactly which characters you want to replace.  The code you are using now is only accepting ASCII character and ignoring non ASCII characters.  With Regex you would need to define all the ASCII characters in your pattern.  So you would have to type up to 255 characters in your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't sure whether the character between those 4 digits is a space or not, you can use a `.` character which matches any character and use this regex to match those group of 4 digits separated by a seemingly unknown character.

```
\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{4}
```

If you want to access those group of 4 digits, then you can put them in group and access them using all four grouping pattern from this regex,

```
(\d{4}).(\d{4}).(\d{4}).(\d{4})
```

**[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/I7jwLD/2)**

Let me know if any of your query remains unresolved.

Comment: your solution seems pattern matching right? Here, I would have some problem.I am going to implement this solution for Redaction to sensitive data. I would redact account number, but if same pattern of social security number presents in the document, that will redact too. this is the problem. "1234 4567 7891 0936" is my parameter. How to do with Exact Match?

Comment: Can you post some sample data for social security number which you say might be present in your input data and might also match? There has to be some distinguishing factor between both else it will be hard to differentiate between the two.

Comment: I meant for example. 
[your Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I7jwLD/3)

In your Demo has this input "5689 6548 7895 6943". why It will be matched. I would match only "1234 4567 7891 0936".that's my requirement.

Comment: @GowthamAlan: Apologies for late reply. If I am correct, you do not want it to match with other similar credit card looking like text which surely contains a space unlike other text containing some unknown character. So to avoid it matching unintended text, you can use `\S` instead of `.` in the regex. This will avoid matching text where you are sure it is a space. Try this regex `\d{4}\S\d{4}\S\d{4}\S\d{4}`

Comment: yep! I have done also you said that.
objBuider.input.autoRedactionRegularExpressions.Add("(?i:\\b" + @"2943\s+1023\s+4832\s+3498" + "\\b)");
those input values are passed by string operation. \s helps to get rid from this unknown char issue.